# Auto Navigate between tabs using using JavaScript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the code to create tabs using HTML, css and plain Javascript. 
Now, I want to be able to toggle between these tabs every 4 seconds.

My code is in the JSFiddle below. (I could not figure out how to add a 'body onload="init()' tag and hence the JsFiddle is not completely functional. Please have a look at the code)
http://jsfiddle.net/qjmDU/1/

I am trying to toggle between the tabs using the following JQuery

```
$(function () {
    //cache a reference to the tabs
    var tabs = $('#tabs li');

    //on click to tab, turn it on, and turn previously-on tab off
    tabs.click(function () { $(this).addClass('on').siblings('.on').removeClass('on'); });

    //auto-rotate every 5 seconds
    setInterval(function () {

        //get currently-on tab
        var onTab = tabs.filter('.on');

        //click either next tab, if exists, else first one
        var nextTab = onTab.index() < tabs.length - 1 ? onTab.next() : tabs.first();
        nextTab.click();
    }, 4000);
});
```

But, have not been able to figure out why the JQuery has no effect. Please help me understand what I am missing. Thanks

Comment: it (your fiddle) seems to work for me on firefox v23

Comment: Please refer this http://jsfiddle.net/qjmDU/1/

Comment: I am not sure how to add the 'body onload="init()' tag on the html there and hence the js function is not effective

Answer (score 0):

Hey so since you stated that you're using jQuery, lets use it to the fullest...

[**CHECK OUT THIS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qjmDU/2/)

I tweeked your fiddle quite a bit. Removed unnecessary functions etc by using jQuery. I didn't monkey with your css however I did remove the body tag from your html since jsfiddle provides you with a body tag already.

To run your init on page load I had to specify that your javascript block executed as though it were in your body tag (a setting of jsfiddle) as well as include the following line of code which is pretty much an equivalent to body.onload:

```
$(window).load(init);
```

Here are your functions re-written with heavy jQuery:

```
function init() {
    // Grab the tab links and content divs from the page
    var tabListItems = $('#tabs li');

    // loop through all tab li tags
    $('#tabs li').each(function(i, ele){
        // Assign click/focus events to the tab anchor/links
        var tabLink = $(this).find('a').on('click', showTab).on('focus', function () { $(this).blur(); });
        var tabBody = $($(tabLink).attr('href'));

        // highlight the first tab
        if (i == 0) $(tabLink).addClass('selected');

        // hide all the content divs but the first
        if (i != 0) $(tabBody).hide();
    });

    //auto-rotate every 4 seconds
    setInterval(function () {
        var selectedTab = $('#tabs').find('li.on');
        var index = $(selectedTab).index();

        if (index < $('#tabs').find('li').length - 1)
            index++;
        else
            index = 0;

        $('#tabs').find('li:eq('+index+') a').click();
    }, 4000);
}

function showTab(e) {
    // prevent default anchor/link action
    e.preventDefault();

    var selectedId = $(this).attr('href');

    // remove 'on' class from all tab li tags
    $('#tabs').find('li').removeClass('on');

    // remove 'selected' class from all tab anchors/links
    $('#tabs').find('a.selected').removeClass('selected');

    // add 'on' class to selected tab li tag
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('on');

    // add selected class 
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    // hide all tab bodies
    $('div.tabContent').hide();

    // show selected tab body
    $(selectedId).show();
}
```

I think I've commented the rest of the code well enough to understand what is going on however if you have any questions or concerns about how it's working please let me know.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello @Ryan, 
I am new to JQuery and it is quite astonishing how it made the task much easier.

Comment: I am trying to use your JQuery in Visual Studio 2012 and deploying it as a webpart on SharePoint 2010. For some reason, the setInterval(function () {} does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: @Sagarika I'm not sure why or how that would prevent the code from working as long as all the html structure, ids and classes you specified in your example mark up didn't change. Maybe check the source of the page as .NET generates it and confirm the markup is exactly what you have in your example js fiddle? Additionally, where is it in your code that you're putting the script block with the code I provided?

Comment: Additionally, being that you're new to jQuery I understand, respect and appreciate the fact you're rolling your own tabs implementation however, instead of trying to reinvent the wheel I'd recommend you take a look at jQuery UI. It's an UI js framework built on top of jQuery. Have a look here for their tab implementation http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/9kaaH/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var timeInterval, tabCount = 0, currnetIndex = 1;
        tabCount = $('ul#tabs').find('li a').length;
        var tabContentObj = $('.tabContent');
        changeTabIndex();
        timeInterval = setInterval(function () { changeTabIndex(); }, 4 * 1000);

        function changeTabIndex() {
            if (currnetIndex > tabCount) {
                currnetIndex = 1;
            }
            tabContentObj.hide();
            $('ul#tabs').find('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
            var currentAncorObj = $('ul#tabs').find('li a').eq(currnetIndex - 1);
            currentAncorObj.parent().addClass('selected');
            $(currentAncorObj.attr('href')).show();
            currnetIndex++;
        };

        $('#tabs li').mouseenter(function () {
            clearInterval(timeInterval);
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            timeInterval = setInterval(function () { changeTabIndex(); }, 4 * 1000);
        });

        $('#tabs li a').click(function () {
            //tabContentObj.hide();
            //$('ul#tabs').find('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
            //var currentAncorObj = $(this);
            //currnetIndex = $('ul#tabs').find('li a').index($(this)) + 1;
            //currentAncorObj.parent().addClass('selected');
            //$(currentAncorObj.attr('href')).show();
            //currnetIndex++;


            //Or

            currnetIndex = $('ul#tabs').find('li a').index($(this)) + 1;
            changeTabIndex();

            //return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: @Ryan, I am trying to use your JQuery in Visual Studio 2012 and deploying it as a webpart on SharePoint 2010. For some reason, the setInterval(function () {}  does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: I am however, able to see the effect when I just use Visual Studio and run it on a browser without the intervention of SharePoint